# How send POST request to a localhost from mobile device?

Tags: docker, networking, postman, expo, port

I'm trying to implement a login in react native + flask app. I have a docker container for my server API. I've run it on my localhost in my computer. I'm also running my front-end on expo. Since it's a different host, how can i send POST request from my mobile device (expo) to the server running on localhost in my computer?

Docker server runs in port 5000 in container. I've mapped the local port 5000 to container's 5000 port.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I hope you are exposing the correct server ports in the docker container.
Then, it can be easily done by using you local machine IP address in your home network instead of "localhost". Maybe your Firewall settings must be changed.

For `React` I usually save the server IP in an .env, so for production I can easily switch the server

Comment: but how to send request from another device?